# Getting streamreader to display specific line from text file c#

Tags: c#, streamreader

Im making a quiz. I have a struct set up, with holds 4 different strings the first is question number, second is question level, the third is the question and the forth is question answer. I have the data for this struct stored in a text file. The idea of the test is that the user will begin the test at level one if they get the question right they will move up to level 2 questions and on. I can't even get the first question to display, this is what I have so far in the section of code that should be displaying the questions. At the minute the cursor in the console windows just blinks repeatedly.

```
 static void quiz(QuestionStruct[] _quiz)
    {
        bool asked = true;
        int score = 0;
        int AmountAsked = 0;

        string level = "1";
        string ans;

        var pathToFile = @"..\..\..\Files\questions.txt";
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathToFile, true))
        {

            while (AmountAsked < 20 || score >= 50)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                int pos = 0;
                if (level == "1" && questions[pos].Level == level) /* when i take && questions[pos].Level == level out of this if statement I get text on the console window but it starts with the question number, then i press enter and i get the question level and so on. */
                {

                    AmountAsked++;
                    questions[pos].Question = sr.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write(questions[pos].Question);
                    ans = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (ans == questions[pos].answer)
                    {
                        level = "2";
                        score = score + 1;
                        while (questions[pos].Level != "2")
                        {
                            pos++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (level == "2" && questions[pos].Level == level)
                {
                    AmountAsked++;
                    questions[pos].Question = sr.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", questions[pos].Question);
                    ans = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (ans == questions[pos].answer)
                    {
                        level = "3";
                        score = score + 2;
                        while (questions[pos].Level != "3")
                        {
                            pos++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        level = "2";
                    }
                }
                if (level == "3" && questions[pos].Level == level)
                {
                    AmountAsked++;
                    questions[pos].Question = sr.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", questions[pos].Question);
                    ans = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (ans == questions[pos].answer)
                    {
                        level = "4";
                        score = score + 3;
                        while (questions[pos].Level != "4")
                        {
                            pos++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        level = "2";
                    }
                }
                if (level == "4" && questions[pos].Level == level)
                {
                    AmountAsked++;
                    questions[pos].Question = sr.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", questions[pos].Question);
                    ans = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (ans == questions[pos].answer)
                    {
                        level = "5";
                        score = score + 4;
                        while (questions[pos].Level != "5")
                        {
                            pos++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        level = "3";
                    }
                }
                while (level == "5" && questions[pos].Level == level)
                {
                    AmountAsked++;
                    questions[pos].Question = sr.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", questions[pos].Question);
                    ans = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (ans == questions[pos].answer)
                    {
                        level = "5";
                        score = score + 5;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        level = "4";
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger and stepping through the code? You should be able to see what it does and why it doesn't output anything. Btw, why is `sr` unused? Confusing.

Comment: Tried it there now, It goes into the while loop, hits the console.clear() and bounces back to the while statement and does this over and over. I don't know what you mean by sr being unused, am i not using it in lines such as this:  questions[pos].Question = sr.ReadLine(); ?

Comment: My mistake. sr is being used. *How* does it "bounce back" to the loop. Why does it not enter any of the if statements? Find out exactly why.

Comment: Some advice: refactor out the common code into a different method, it will make your code more readable and maintainable. The code in the branches looks very similar, refactor it out.

Comment: If questions[0] is not level 1 it will loop forever, you don't increment pos in that case

Comment: If you comment out Console.Clear(), does it step through the code right?? Also if your score ever exceeds 50, I can't find an exit on the outer loop. Is that really what you want?

Comment: usr, lead me on the right path. I inserted questions[pos].Level = sr.ReadLine(); outside the if statement and it worked. Cheers.